# How can I add text to a Python 3 matplotlib legend while plotting object attributes in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to add text to legend entries in Python 3 using matplotlib so that I can label them, for example there are three different curves in a plot and they all correspond to different variable values used to generate the curves, but right now the legend only plots the variable value and not the name of the variable. For example, if I am plotting three different lines with different slope, the legend gives the value of the slope (i.e. a number, 4), but I want the legend to say "slope = 4" and not just 4. My code is here:

```
def plotter(to_plot, var, *args):
    """Plots different object variables"""
    list_of_objs=[arg for arg in args]
    for obj in list_of_objs:
        plt.plot(a.f_in, getattr(obj, to_plot))
        plt.xlabel('Flux',fontsize='xx-large')
        plt.ylabel(to_plot,fontsize='xx-large')
        plt.xticks(fontsize='xx-large')
        plt.yticks(fontsize='xx-large')
        for_legend = [str(getattr(obj,var)) for obj in list_of_objs]
        plt.legend(for_legend ,fontsize='xx-large')
        plt.show()
```

The code takes a list of class objects that create different curves on the plot. As of now the legend only prints the value of the variable given by the values stored in `for_legend`, but I want it to be `var = for_legend`. Any tips here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `obj` is a custom class, then you could create a method with the desired behaviour? Alternately, `for_legend = ["Slope = {}".format(str(getattr(obj,var))) for obj in list_of_objs]` may work if the variable is always slope, it's hard to say definitively without seeing how you're calling the function or knowing what your list of objects is made up of. You also refer to `a.f_in` without explaining what `a` is?

Comment: Just spotted that I misread this a little:
`for_legend = [f"{var} = {str(getattr(obj,var))}" for obj in list_of_objs]`

Comment: Wow this works, thanks a ton!!